# How do I fix error "requires a primary key to be defined"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a Blazor server app that lets users CRUD expenses. Whenever I run the app, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'TipoDeDespesa' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

This is my `EndToEndContext`:

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace EndToEndDB.Data.EndToEnd
{
    public partial class EndtoEndContext : DbContext
    {
        public EndtoEndContext()
        {
        }

        public EndtoEndContext(DbContextOptions<EndtoEndContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Despesa> Despesa { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TipoDeDespesa> TipoDeDespesa { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail, "EmailIndex");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName, "UserNameIndex")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Despesa>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.DespesaId).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Date).HasColumnType("datetime");
                
                entity.Property(e => e.EstadoDespesa).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Titulo).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                    .HasMaxLength(450)
                    .HasColumnName("UserID");

                entity.Property(e => e.ValorDespesa).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.IdTipoDeDespesaNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Despesa)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdTipoDeDespesa)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Despesa__IdTipoD__2739D489");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Despesa)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Despesa__UserID__2645B050");

            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TipoDeDespesa>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IdTipoDespesa)
                    .HasName("PK__TipoDeDe__080827EE7DE3B25B");

                entity.Property(e => e.IdTipoDespesa).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Tipo)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Let me know if you need other portions of the code.

Thanks!

I tried to run the app but keep getting an error.

Comment: This looks more like it's an EF Core issue than a Blazor issue - I suspect you could reproduce this in a [mcve] which is just a console app. That would be helpful... along with providing more information about where the exception is being thrown. (I suspect you only need a single entity to reproduce the error, too.)

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal yes it does.

Comment: This is a EF error, but I notice that only one table as a Primary key, the other 2 doesn't have one (unless you are setting them on the model)

Comment: @Camadas how do I change that then?

Comment: EF recognizes `DespesaId` as key by name conventions. I wonder what `AspNetUsers` is doing in this context. Normally it's part of an `IdentityDbContext`. Since `TipoDeDespesa` has its key defined in this context class, I wonder if the exception is thrown from this context. Do you maybe have more context classes? As always: it helps to show the code that actually throws the exception.